# run asp.net 3.5 sites on asp.net 4.0 without changing code\web.config

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible?

Comment: If you're using IIS7, you need to remove references to 3.5 assemblies/compilers. Edit: I suppose it depends what's in your web.config file. If you're referring to running 3.5 applications on the 4.0 framework, you can, but you'll need to put your applications in different app pools.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have only one application pool, so I will upgrade projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you have .NET 3.5 installed. Otherwise you will have to upgrade since .NET 4.0 has its own CLR.

See ASP.NET Side-by-Side Execution Overview :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a99txfy5.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are subtle breaking-changes, many of which are for he better IMHO.

You'll need to set up seperate application pools targetting the appropriate framework and placing your 3.5/4.0 sites in the right pool.

Comment: @Gorilla: Thanks for the edit - 3.4 would have been mysterious!

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Both options are available in VS 2010. Just take care of functionality like ajax. It may stop you running old apps in new C #.

Comment: Options might be available in VS 2010, but what about server ?